# What is the correct (Scottish) pronunciation of "Paechter"?

Tags: pronunciation, british-english

What is the correct (Scottish) pronunciation of "Paechter"?

The best I have found is [this link](https://www.howtopronounce.com/paechter) in which there are two different ways of saying the name. Can one shed some light on the difference and the one which is common to be heard in Scotland?

Comment: I have never heard this German word used or pronounced in Scotland. I see no point to this question.

Comment: @Anton: I need to introduce a Scottish person in a talk whose surname is this.

Comment: Clarify 'Scottish'. Highland or Lowland? East or West? Mainland or island? Morningside or Gorbals?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: He is from Edinburgh. But I don't know how that fits into the categories you noted.

Comment: Can't you ask the person beforehand how they pronounce their name? You can hardly refer to a surname of German origin as 'commonly heard in Scotland'.

Comment: @KateBunting: I hoped for some clues here, but it seems I have to directly ask.

Comment: My guess would be P as in press, pen, pack, ae as in the Scots word brae (like ay in hay, say, pay), ch as in the Scots word loch, and ter as a Scot might say the end of pointer, with the final 'r' rolled. Note that most of it is in the Scots word [teuchter](https://forvo.com/word/teuchter/) (careful! this word is a Lowland Scots word originally used to describe a Scottish Highlander and may be heard as insulting). All this assumes he is actually Scottish and not someone who was born elsewhere went there to work. Or whose family has roots elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I have never heard this name used publicly and doubt it is common here. If you cannot check with the person beforehand, why not simply use the German pronunciation? At least German and Scots both use the guttural version of "ch" so that should put you on safe ground. I do not recommend using the simple k sound; that would jar with a Scots  audience in the same way that it would snigger at "Lo**ck** Ness" rather than "Lo**ch** Ness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Names can't be reliably pronounced.  While Smith is usually /smɪθ/ I'm sure there are some who pronounce it /smɑɪð/.

It is culturally quite acceptable to ask how to pronounce someone's name, especially if the name uses unorthodox spelling or is unfamiliar. I'm often asked how to pronounce my (Alsatian) name, and it is always **nice** to be asked; it shows interest and care. It's less acceptable to pronounce someone's name incorrectly *when you've had the opportunity* to ask how it should be pronounced.  And it is generally acceptable for a non-native speaker to make errors that don't affect communication.

If there is no way to ask, then following typical pronunciation would result in /pɛχtər/ But using this would be less preferable to simply asking.

Answer (score 0):

To use this name in an introduction:

I have never heard this name used publicly and it is not common here in Scotland. If you cannot check with the person beforehand, why not simply use the German pronunciation? At least German and Scots both use the guttural version of "ch" so that should put you on safe ground.

I do not recommend using the simple "k" sound; that would jar with a Scots audience in the same way that it would snigger at "Lo**ck** Ness" rather than "Lo**ch** Ness.

If you don't habitually make this sound, try clearing your throat noisily or - even better - listen to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cMkoHt73loQ

Comment: In the pronunciation examples of 'teuchter' that I linked to above, the contributor named 'Mackintosh' says more or less with a hard 'k' whereas 'Perthshire' says it more gutturally, at least to my Sassenach ear.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Interesting but I believe Mackintosh is in a minority regarding teuchter. Along all west Coast, Highlands and from Perthshire northwards I normally hear it more guttural. In any case, Paechter appears to be German so the voiced guttural German "ch" seems appropriate.